# How can I get an one to one object without with only one related entities?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a Book class that contains an InventoryItem and the InventoryItem contains the Book, so the relationship is One to One. If I want to get the Inventory item it will return the Book that contains that InventoryItem and so on. I want to return that InventoryItem as IActionResult.

**Book class:**

```
public string Title { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<Author> Authors { get; set; }
public Category Category { get; set; }
public string Isbn { get; set; }
public string PublishingHouse { get; set; }
public string Edition { get; set; }
public InventoryItem InventoryItem { get; set; }
public bool IsDamaged { get; set; }
public bool IsLost { get; set; }
```

**InventoryItem class:**

```
public Guid BookId { get; set; }
public Book Book { get; set; }
public int Number { get; set; }
public AcquisitionDetail AcquisitionDetail { get; set; }
```

**The method that return InventoryItem:**

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<InventoryItem>> GetInventoryItemsAsync()
{
    return await schoolLibraryContext.InventoryItems.Include(inventoryItem => inventoryItem.Book)
        .Include(inventoryItem => inventoryItem.AcquisitionDetail)
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

**Question:** How can I include only one Book object without the InventoryItem when I want to return the InventoryItem.

Comment: If you're using this to return via a API you could create a ViewModel and use AutoMapper to map the properties you want to present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume question is about Entity Framework, since it is in tags.

**In terms of using data in app:**

In such case, you don't really gave to worry about it. Unless you specifically ask about it using `Include`, `Book` will be lazy loaded, that is, it won't be sent in initial query, and in case you actually use it, another query will be sent to retrieve it.

Be wary though, lazy loading can save a lot of traffic, but it can also easily cause "N+1" problem, where you constantly send queries even though you could just load whole entity at once. So if you happen to actually use `Book` later, it might be better idea to use `Include` and load initially, executing queries is relatively expensive when compared to data traffic.

**In terms of sending this data outside (through API)**

Don't ever return your entity outside. It's really bad practice even if you actually want to return all of its properties.

If you return your data outside, you should map it to an object of other class, and then return this class. This way you make sure that you don't ever send too much data, e.g. by expanding your entity with properties you don't want to send outside.

In your case it could look like:

```
public class BookModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<AuthorModel> Authors { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public string Isbn { get; set; }
    public string PublishingHouse { get; set; }
    public string Edition { get; set; }
    public bool IsDamaged { get; set; }
    public bool IsLost { get; set; }
}

public class InventoryItemModel
{
    public Guid BookId { get; set; }
    public BookModel Book { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public AcquisitionDetailModel AcquisitionDetail { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thank you for the answer. But if I use lazy load, I need to make object properties virtual, no? I also tried to map the entity to model, but it doesn't work, I got the same object, but in a model. Maybe, I don't understand something.

Comment: Look at snippet in my answer. One of reasons you map entity to model is to remove loop in navigation properties. In this case, `InventoryItemModel` contains reference to `BookModel`, but `BookModel` no longer contains reference to `InventoryItemModel`, so if you map your entity to this model before sending it through API, you will only get one copy of book, instead of this endless loop.

Comment: And yes, if you want to use lazy loading, properties should be virtual. It's good practice to have all properties virtual, instantly after fetching entity from Context map it to Model/DTO (Data-transfer-object, in most cases it's identical to entity, except for the fact its properties are not virtual, and it's immutable, that is, properties are only set in constructor, you make a change, you make new object) and sending data outside means mapping DTO to ViewModel, which contains only data you want to show.

Comment: I'd suggest you to read about MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel), you should then understand why is it important to separate all of these.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will mark your answer as correct. That was my mistake, the BookModel doesn't contain the InventoryItemModel. But I recommend you to take a look at this post about lazy loading: [https://ardalis.com/avoid-lazy-loading-entities-in-asp-net-applications](https://ardalis.com/avoid-lazy-loading-entities-in-asp-net-applications).

Comment: Oh, I know about issues with lazy loading, that's why I mentioned "N+1" problem. But it has its advantages, and when you work with huge database, it can really save a lot of traffic (provided you actually write it so it still uses just one query) though unless you need to, having it disabled may not be bad idea actually, that's true.